# Apache naming for TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Tags: tls, apache, ciphers, debian

[According to NIST and HIPAA guidance](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/?id=eddba385c2f8f513d65a3d412850161da2c7eb1c7c7b9b0ccd685781468f3e4c), I miss one cipher on a new web server:

> ```
> TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
> ```

Despite I read this one is discouraged, I am curious as to how do I add it?

---

I am on Linux Debian 9 with Apache.

Currently I have set up these ciphers:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!eNULL:!ADH:!EXP:!LOW:!DES:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4
```

---

I tried hard to find a naming for this suite [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) for example, unsuccessfully.

Does anyone know its naming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Apache naming" is actually the syntax used by OpenSSL. According to https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html the OpenSSL name for TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
 is DES-CBC3-SHA.